# how do I subquery many to many in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a subquery over a many to many with the following code.

```
    SELECT e.ep_suragate_pk  FROM episode e 
    JOIN (
      SELECT n.name FROM actor n 
      JOIN episode_actor ea 
      ON n.act_suragate_pk = ea.act_suragate_pk
      ) ep_act 
    ON ep_act.ep_suragate_pk = e.ep_suragate_pk;
```

I'm getting an ORA-00904: invalid indentifier error but all the columns exist.

```
     episode
     -------
     ep_suragate_pk


     episode_actor
     -------------
     ep_suragate_pk
     act_suragate_pk


     actor
     -----
     act_suragate_pk
```

If someone can help me understand where I'm going wrong it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need all these sub queries

```
select  e.ep_suragate_pk  
from    episode e  , episode_actor ea , actor n
where   ea.ref_id = e.ep_suragate_pk
and     n.act_suragate_pk = ea.act_suragate_pk
```

Answer (score 3):

The subquery needs to select column `ea.ep_suragate_pk` in order to resolve the invalid identifier issue. Not yet sure if that will get the results you want though.

Comment: Many thanks. You are right on both accounts. I've give n.name an alias  and used select e.ep_suragate_pk, ep_act.AliasName to get the correct info-in the first query.

Answer (score 2):

Inner query

```
   (
  SELECT n.name FROM actor n 
  JOIN episode_actor ea 
  ON n.act_suragate_pk = ea.act_suragate_pk
  ) ep_act
```

does not have column p_suragate_pk for joining

```
  ep_act 
ON ep_act.ep_suragate_pk = e.ep_suragate_pk;
```

so you can modify like this

```
SELECT e.ep_suragate_pk  FROM episode e 
JOIN (
  SELECT n.name,n.act_suragate_pk FROM actor n 
  JOIN episode_actor ea 
  ON n.act_suragate_pk = ea.act_suragate_pk
  ) ep_act 
ON ep_act.ep_suragate_pk = e.ep_suragate_pk;
```

Answer (score 1):

The column you using for joining should be selected. So try:

```
SELECT e.ep_suragate_pk  FROM episode e 
JOIN (
  SELECT n.name, ref_id FROM actor n 
  JOIN episode_actor ea 
  ON n.act_suragate_pk = ea.act_suragate_pk
  ) ep_act 
ON ep_act.ref_id = e.ep_suragate_pk;
```